# Onmouseover with jquery not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm a js/jQuery newbie. I have tried to add some code to a div that changes its class on mouse over. It works fine in FF, Chrome, and IE9. But in IE8 and IE7, its not working. What am I doing wrong? The code is:

```
<div class="calloutHover" onmouseover="$(this).attr('class', 'calloutHoverOver')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('class', 'calloutHover')" >
```

Comment: Your code looks fine (not perfect, but it should do the job). What error are you getting? What does the div contain?

Comment: Just tested with [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/aTV3E/), and it works fine... Note: I've changed to .html to actually see the change.

Comment: do you have a valid doctype declared?

Comment: I'm using:`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Oops. I got it now. Turns out it wasn't the js. It was the CSS. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Knowing it wasn't the JS made me examine the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in that ie8 may not recognize class as an attr. So use

```
$(yourelement).addClass('yourclass')
```

Best to do this somewhere after the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#yourdivId').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('calloutHover');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('calloutHover');
});
</script>
```

It keeps all the code separate from your HTML, if there's no id, then you can apply a class to all the divs you would like to behave this way and apply the behavior to all of them at once.

(using the second method also means you're relying on jQuery to correctly handle ie8's unique behavior.)